# How to save list of dictionaries to Excel or CSV file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, dictionary

I am trying to save a list of dictionaries in an Excel or CSV file in Python.

Dictionary data sample:

```
[
 {'Area of expertise': ['Acne', 'Skin cancer', 'Moles'],
  'Health insurance': ["I'm paying for myself",
                       'Alliance Health Group',
                       'Allianz',
                       'AVIVA'],
  'Language spoken': ['English', 'Hindi'],
  'Name': 'Nikhil',
  'Ratings': '5',
  'Types of offering': ['Call']},
 {'Area of expertise': ['Acne',
                        'Skin cancer',
                        'Moles',
                        'Lichen sclerosus',
                        'Psoriasis'],
  'Health insurance': ["I'm paying for myself"],
  'Language spoken': ['English'],
  'Name': 'Akhil',
  'Ratings': '5',
  'Types of offering': ['Call']}
]
```

How can I do that?

Comment: try pandas but you have to structure the data so all the lists/columns have the same length `pd.DataFrame(data: list[dict]).to_csv(filepath) or .to_excel(filepath)`

Comment: Do you want to save the data as they are, or transform them beforehand into a more 2-dimensional format?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use `pandas` -

```
import pandas as pd

data = "your dictionary data"

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_excel('dict_data.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
df.to_csv('dict_data.csv')
```